# .htaccess dash separator 2 params or more

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm working with `.htaccess`, and I just want to make friendly URLs.

My current URL:

```
www.url.com/index.php?v=[SOMETHING]&i=[IDIOM]
```

But it can also be:

```
www.url.com/index.php?v=[SOMETHING]
```

What I want:

```
www.url.com/[SOMETHING]-[IDIOM]
```

Or in the second case:

```
www.url.com/[SOMETHING]
```

`.htaccess` config I made:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)?$ index.php?v=$1&i=$2
```

Writing `www.url.com/[SOMETHING]-[IDIOM]` goes okay, with the webpage running properly.
But in the second case I have to write `www.url.com/[SOMETHING]**-**`. If I write `www.url.com/[SOMETHING]` the page breaks.

So, I want to make the second param optional, and separated by a dash if it's possible.

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It won't match `www.url.com/[SOMETHING]` because it expects a `-` at the end. Include the `-` inside the second capturing group, like so:

`^([^/]+?)(-[^/]+)?$`

Also changed the first greedy quantifier to a lazy one to avoid matching too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the second rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)?$ index.php?v=$1&i=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?v=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a project called Helium. The documentation is available here : Visit https://github.com/iamyogik/Helium

It will do all this stuff for you and you do not have to worry about anything. You can pass variable parameters between `/{var1}/{var2}/` and also use `$_GET or $_POST` requests at the same time.